# Add Multiple Row In A Table and Nested Row In The Same Row

Tags: javascript, jquery

With `jQuery`, most of the time we add rows one by one in a table or delete them. But in my case, the requirement is bit different. Say I've a table and have to add new row and tested the below:

*HTML*:

```
<button class="addRow"> 
    Add New Row
</button> 

<table> 
    <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th>Rows</th> 
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Row 0</td> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

*Script*:

```
<script> 
    var lineNo = 1; 
    var html = ""; 

    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $(".addRow").click(function () { 
            html = "<tr><td>Row" + lineNo + "</td></tr>"; //Binding line no 
            tableBody = $("table tbody"); //Getting table element with selector 
            tableBody.append(html); //Appending the table row 
            lineNo++; //Counter to keep track of added rows
        }); 
    });  
</script>
```

So with a click event, I am adding multiple rows or rows one by one. But I am not sure if I can achieve this feature. Say with adding new rows to a table, I've to add more rows in the same row. As an example, adding multiple rows seem like this:

```
product size color price //Column

product1 size1 color1 price1 //Row
product2 size2 color2 price2
```

In my case, I require to do the following:

```
product size color price //Column

product1 size1 color1(+) price1 //Row
product2 size2 color2(+) price2
               color2(-)
               color2(-)
               color2(-)
product3 size3 color3(+) price3
product4 size4 color4(+) price4
               color4(-)
               color4(-)
               color4(-)
```

There will be add row option (+) in the newly created row, so user can add or remove rows and require to keep the track, say product1 with multiple colors will be assigned to that specific product 1 and so on. I am expecting ideas to implement this feature efficiently and look forward to hear from experts.

Comment: " I am expecting ideas to implement this feature efficiently and look forward to hear from experts." - This is not the purpose of Stack Overflow.  You need to present an issue that conforms with the expected question formats defined in [ask].  Soliciting generic feedback/ideas is too broad.

Answer (score 2):

I create a snippet that is able to add any number of rows (not fool-proof):

```js
// initial data
// container for keepeng items
let data = [{
    id: 0,
    size: 10
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    size: 12
  },
]

// START: DOM manipulation functions
const cellTemplate = (cell) => {
  return `<td>${ cell }</td>`
}

const rowTemplate = (row) => {
  let html = ''
  html += '<tr>'
  Object.entries(row).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    html += cellTemplate(value)
  })
  html += `<td><button class="removeRow" data-rowid=${ row.id }>Remove</button></td>`
  html += '</tr>'
  return html
}

const tbodyTemplate = (data) => {
  let html = ''
  data.forEach(e => {
    html += rowTemplate(e)
  })
  return html
}

const updateTbody = (data) => {
  jQuery("tbody").html(tbodyTemplate(data))
}

// END: DOM manipulation functions

// calculating new ID (very sloppy, but it's OK for a snippet)
const nextId = (data) => {
  const nextIdx = Math.max.apply(null, data.map(({ id }) => id)) + 1
  return nextIdx < 0 ? 0 : nextIdx
}

// adding ANY number of items to the
// item container (data)
const addItem = (data, number) => {
  const d = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
  for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    d.push({
      id: nextId(d),
      size: 9 + i
    })
  }
  return d
}

// init view
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  updateTbody(data)

  // add one row
  $('.addRow').on('click', function() {
    data = addItem(data, 1)
    updateTbody(data) // updating DOM with the new dataset
  })

  // add number of rows based on input
  $('.addMoreRows').on('click', function() {
    const numRows = $('#rowNum').val()
    data = addItem(data, numRows)
    updateTbody(data) // updating DOM with the new dataset
  })

  // remove one row
  // watch out for the dynamic binding!
  $('body').on('click', '.removeRow', function() {
    const id = Number($(this).attr("data-rowid"))
    const idx = data.indexOf(data.find(e => e.id === id))
    data.splice(idx, 1)
    updateTbody(data) // updating DOM with the new dataset
  })
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
tr,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

thead {
  background: gray;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

tbody tr:nth-child( 2n) {
  background: lightgray
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="addRow"> 
    Add New Row
</button><br />
<button class="addMoreRows"> 
    Add New Rows
</button>
<label for="rowNum">How many rows do you want to add?<input id="rowNum" type="number" value=1 min=1 max=10 /></label>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th>Manage</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The main idea is that nothing keeps track of the number of items (explicitly), but everything is based on "one source of truth": the `data` array (of objects). If you manipulate this array & update the **DOM** based on the manipulated array, then the table is modified accordingly.

If you modify the item container (`data`) and the templates (`tbody`, `row`, `cell`) according to your presentational needs, then you can add & remove any number of rows - without diving into chaos.

You can create sub-items, sub-sub-items, and functions that remove only one sub-item or the main item altogether. The logic is simple: only modify the data & then update the DOM based on templates. (Meaning: first create your data structure, the functions that can manipulate that structure as you require, and only then wrap it up in a table with buttons.)

### UPDATE

#### 1. Create the data structure that represents your case

```js
let data = [{
    id: 0,
    size: 10,
    color: "red",
    price: 12,
    variants: [{
        size: 12
      },
      {
        size: 14
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    size: 10,
    color: "blue",
    price: 15,
    variants: [{
        size: 12
      },
      {
        size: 14
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The data structure above shows that we have two items, and each item has two more variants (sub-items).

#### 2. Create the functions that modify (mutate) the structure:

```js
let data = [{
    id: 0,
    size: 10,
    color: "red",
    price: 12,
    variants: [{
        id: "0_1",
        size: 12
      },
      {
        id: "0_2",
        size: 14
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    size: 10,
    color: "blue",
    price: 15,
    variants: [{
        id: "1_1",
        size: 12
      },
      {
        id: "1_2",
        size: 14
      }
    ]
  }
]

// mocking a new item
const newItem = {
  id: 2,
  size: 10,
  color: "orange",
  price: 8,
  variants: [{
      id: "2_1",
      size: 12
    },
    {
      id: "2_2",
      size: 14
    }
  ]
}

const addItem = (data, newItem) => {
  let d = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
  d = [...d, newItem]
  return d
}

const addSubItem = (data, itemId, subItem) => {
  let d = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
  let item = d.find(({
    id
  }) => id === itemId)
  item.variants = [...item.variants, subItem]
  return d
}

const removeItem = (data, itemId) => {
  let d = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
  const idx = d.indexOf(d.find(({ id }) => id == itemId))
  if (idx !== -1) {
    d.splice(idx, 1)
  }
  return d
}

const removeSubItem = (data, subItemId) => {
  let d = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
  d.forEach(({ variants }) => {
    const variant = variants.find(({ id }) => id === subItemId)
    if (variant) {
      const idx = variants.indexOf(variant)
      if (idx !== -1) {
        variants.splice(idx, 1)
      }
    }
  })
  return d
}

// original data
console.log('original data:', data)

// adding item
data = addItem(data, newItem)
console.log('after adding new item:', data)

// adding sub-item
data = addSubItem(data, 1, {
  id: "1_3",
  size: 15
})
console.log('after adding new sub-item:', data)

// removing item
data = removeItem(data, 0)
console.log('after removing item:', data)

// removing sub-item
data = removeSubItem(data, "2_1")
console.log('after removing sub-item:', data)
```

OK, now we have four functions to modify the data:

- `addItem`
- `addSubItem`
- `removeItem`
- `removeSubItem`

#### 3. Wrap it in HTML

```js
let data = [{
    id: 0,
    size: 10,
    color: "red",
    price: 12,
    variants: [{
        id: "0_1",
        size: 12
      },
      {
        id: "0_2",
        size: 14
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    size: 10,
    color: "blue",
    price: 15,
    variants: [{
        id: "1_1",
        size: 12
      },
      {
        id: "1_2",
        size: 14
      },
      {
        id: "1_2",
        color: "beige"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const headers = ["id", "size", "color", "price"]

const createTableArray = (data, headers) => {
  const items = data.map(item => {
    const itemRow = headers.map(header => {
      return item[header]
    })
    const subItemRows = item.variants.map(variant => {
      return headers.map(header => {
        return variant[header] || ''
      })
    })
    return [itemRow, ...subItemRows]
  })
  return [headers, ...items]
}

const tableTemplate = (tableArray) => {
  let html = ''
  tableArray.forEach((e, i, d) => {
    let row = ''
    if (!i) {
      row += '<tr>'
      e.forEach(attrs => {
        row += `<th>${ attrs }</th>`
      })
        row += `<th>manage</th>`
      row += '</tr>'
    } else {
      e.forEach(attrs => {
        row += `<tr>`
        attrs.forEach(attr => {
          row += `<td>${ attr }</td>`
        })
        row += `<td><button class="removeItem" data-itemid="${ attrs[0] }">REMOVE</button></td>`
        row += '</tr>'
      })
    }
    html += row
  })
  return html
}

const updateTable = (tableArray) => {
  document.querySelector('table').innerHTML = tableTemplate(tableArray)
}

const tableArray = createTableArray(data, headers)
updateTable(tableArray)

// mocking a new item
const newItem = {
  id: 2,
  size: 10,
  color: "orange",
  price: 8,
  variants: [{
      id: "2_1",
      size: 12
    },
    {
      id: "2_2",
      size: 14
    }
  ]
}

const addItem = (data, newItem) => {
  let d = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
  d = [...d, newItem]
  return d
}

const addSubItem = (data, itemId, subItem) => {
  let d = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
  let item = d.find(({ id }) => id === itemId)
  item.variants = [...item.variants, subItem]
  return d
}

const removeItem = (data, itemId) => {
  let d = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
  const idx = d.indexOf(d.find(({ id }) => id == itemId))
  if (idx !== -1) {
    d.splice(idx, 1)
  }
  return d
}

const removeSubItem = (data, subItemId) => {
  let d = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
  d.forEach(({ variants }) => {
    const variant = variants.find(({ id }) => id === subItemId)
    if (variant) {
      const idx = variants.indexOf(variant)
      if (idx !== -1) {
        variants.splice(idx, 1)
      }
    }
  })
  return d
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#addItem").on('click', function() {
    data = addItem(data, newItem)
    updateTable(createTableArray(data, headers))
  })
  $("body").on('click', '.removeItem', function() {
    const itemId = $(this).data("itemid")
    const before = data.length
    data = removeItem(data, itemId)
    if (before === data.length) {
      data = removeSubItem(data, itemId)
    }
    updateTable(createTableArray(data, headers))
  })
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, tr, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addItem">ADD ONE ITEM</button><br />
<table>
</table>
```

Now we are there:

- data structure is ready
- data can be modified (items & sub-items added and removed)
- UI (HTML) in place (adding one item, removing sub-items by line, removing items with its sub-items)

There are some problems with the snippet (ID of lines is coupled with the position of the ID in an array), no sub-items (variants) can be added through the UI. But I think with a little work it can be modified to do anything you needed.

Comment: I really appreciate it @muka.gergely and already tried the same thing. But is it possible in each row I can only add the sizes separately? So with adding new rows, there would be option to add sub rows say multiple size as well.

Comment: @user8512043 yes, it's possible. The basic thing: create the data structure that represents the logic of your case; THEN create the functions that modify (mutate) the data; THEN wrap it up in an HTML as you see fit. I'll update my answer with these steps.