# Add Multiple Options Row Wise To A Table Column

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement assigning multiple options to a question and used `jQuery` to do so. Though my requirement has been changed, so was doing some R & D and fortunately got this thread - [Add Multiple Row In A Table and Nested Row In The Same Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63269765/add-multiple-row-in-a-table-and-nested-row-in-the-same-row). Almost identical and the solution provided seems pretty complex. So I was trying to implement mine as follows:

```js
$('tbody tr').find('td').parent(); //Traversing to tr Element
   
//Add row to the table
$('#btnAddRow').on('click', function() {
    var lastRow = $('#tblQuesAns tbody tr:last').html();

    $('#tblQuesAns tbody').append('<tr>' + lastRow + '</tr>');
    $('#tblQuesAns tbody tr:last input').val('');
});

//Add more rows for option
$('body').on('click', '.addOptions', function() {
$('#tblQuesAns td:eq(2)').append('<tr><td><input  id="val" type="text" /></tr>'); //Getting the second column as I've to add multiple rows here
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnAddRow" type="button">
    Add Row
</button>
<table id="tblQuesAns" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="txtQuestion" value="Capital of Englnad" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="txtOptions" value="London" />
                <span class="addOptions">(+)</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="txtQuestion" value="Current Pandemic" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="txtOptions" value="Corona" />
                <span class="addOptions">(+)</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am pretty sure, I am close enough but how can I align the text boxes along the options, say when I click on **Add Row** button, it will create two new text boxes and the second column will have a plus sign that'll again create more options (Rows) for that particular row and so on? Now the text boxes generated are aligned randomly.

**N.B**: In the code sample, these are two questions. So I've to create specific and separate options for those two. There could be any number of questions with options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the click event handler `this` is the element the event occurred on.

Using `this` you could append to the parent of the button clicked, something like:

```js
//Add row to the table
$('#btnAddRow').on('click', function() {
    var $clone = $('#tblQuesAns tbody tr:last').clone();
    $clone.find('input').val('')
    $('#tblQuesAns tbody').append($clone);
   
});

//Add more rows for option
$('body').on('click', '.addOptions', function() { 
   $(this).parent().append('<div><input  class="txtOptions" type="text" /></div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnAddRow" type="button">
    Add Row
</button>
<table id="tblQuesAns" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="txtQuestion" value="Capital of Englnad" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="txtOptions" value="London" />
                <span class="addOptions">(+)</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="txtQuestion" value="Current Pandemic" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="txtOptions" value="Corona" />
                <span class="addOptions">(+)</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then when it's time to collect all the data you can do something like:

```
const allData = $('#tblQuesAns tbody tr').map(function() {
  const $row = $(this),
    question = $row.find('.txtQuestion').val(),
    options = $row.find('.txtOptions').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get();

  return {  question,  options };

}).get();
```

Comment: Just perfect @charlietfl. Just one more thing, if I try to get those specific values say the options for question one, how could I do that and is it possible to use a delimiter to obtain them?

Comment: I wrote how to get all values for all rows at bottom of answer. Would be similar if you only need one at a time. Just don't use the outer `map()`

Comment: Oh! Come on. I was dump enough, didn't observe that. Thanks a ton @charlietfl, almost there. Let me do a testing and will get back to you asap.

Comment: Are you there @charlietfl?

Comment: See this - https://jsfiddle.net/osx0w1dq/ @charlietfl. When I click on the plus sign, it generates text boxes but when I click on the newly generated text box for options, it creates text boxes as well. Seems like the click event got some issues.

Comment: Am confused what expected behavior is. Don't understand why you append to the plus icon span. Clicking on the inputs you append to it is also a click on the plus span

Comment: So what should I do to align the plus sign, I mean keeping it out of appending? Any better way?

Comment: Your solution is just fine. But the problem is I always append the last row to the table that means if any row has previous options, then it binds the same thing when I add new row. I guess, I made it clear.

Comment: Store a clone of an empty one to start with on page load. Then clone that each time you do insert